# Rebuild linux API

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, rebuild

I need to compile an API test on debian, but following error appears:

> root@beaglebone:~# ./H264_UVC_TestAP
>
> v1.0.14.0_H264_UVC_TestAP_Multi
>
> your kernel version: 0x30813
>
> TestAP support kernel version: 0x030244
>
> TestAP didn't match current kernel version, please rebuild TestAP
>   argc value: 1, ./H264_UVC_TestAP, (null), SSH_AGENT_PID=2748
>   Error opening device (null):14.

I follow these steps to solve this issue, and load a compatible kernel version with the API:

> wget -c https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.8.2.tar.xz
>   tar-xvJf linux-3.8.2.tar.xz cd linux-3.8.2
>   cp/boot/config-3.8.13-bone47.config

afther that another error appears:

> cp: missing destination file operand after'/boot/config-3.8.13-bone47-config'

any help?

Comment: Yeah, `cp` command takes 2 arguments, so you need to specify where to copy your file. Like `cp /boot/config-3.8.13-bone47 .config`. Also make sure that the file you are trying to copy exists (before actual copying).